# How to change specific row color in list control depending on text present in specific column?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, win32gui, clistctrl

I am using MFC function `OnCustomDraw` to change the text color of a row. But instead of specific row all the rows in list control gets red color. I have added condition also to check the text. In my listCtrl 7th column has passport details like "Yes" and "No". So if someone has "No" passport then only that row text should be red. Please help me on this. I am using below code.

```
void CMyListClass::OnCustomdrawMyList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>(pNMHDR);

    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    if (CDDS_PREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
    }
    else if (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        COLORREF crText;

        int nCol = 6;
        CString m_SearchThisItemText = _T("No");

        for (int i = 0; i < m_list.GetItemCount(); ++i)
        {
            CString szText = m_list.GetItemText(i, nCol);
            if (szText == m_SearchThisItemText)
            {
                crText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        pLVCD->clrText = crText;

        *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    }
}
```

I tried to fetch the subitem coloring but no success.

Comment: `dwItemSpec` contains the item index.

Comment: but how to compare sub item data with any other string as dwItemSpec contains index only??

Comment: You call `GetItemText()`. `dwItemSpec` is the item, and the column is, as you explained, at fixed index 6.

Comment: Use `CMFCListCtrl`, which is derived from `CListCtrl`. It will make your life a lot easier for customization. I used it in the past for custom colouring and I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask for the `CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW` and have to check for state `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM`

```
if (CDDS_PREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
   *pResult  = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW|CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;  // request notifications for individual items
else if (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
   *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;     
else if ((CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT | CDDS_SUBITEM) == pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
   ...
```

The code might be easier with a switch/case.

See sample here https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=24114

Comment: Why would you need to do this? And if you do, how do you then change the color of the previous six items? The question is how to render the *entire* row in a different text color. The question is **not** how to display text in a specific column of a particular row using a different color.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```cpp
        for (int i = 0; i < m_list.GetItemCount(); ++i)
        {
            CString szText = m_list.GetItemText(i, nCol);
            if (szText == m_SearchThisItemText)
            {
                crText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
```

This iterates over **all** items and checks whether any match the predicate. If a single item matches the predicate, all rows will be rendered using red text color.

What you need to do instead is evaluate the current item only. The current item index is provided through the `dwItemSpec` field of the [`NMCUSTOMDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmcustomdraw) structure.

The following fixes your code:

```cpp
        int i = static_cast<int>(pLVCD->nmcd.dwItemSpec);
        CString szText = m_list.GetItemText(i, nCol);
        if (szText == m_SearchThisItemText)
        {
            pLVCD->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        }
```